# Show Different Divs based on query result

Tags: php

Here what I got in view

[image]

I want to show it as Separate divs based on vendor name

[image]

How can i Group the vandor names and Show in different divs ?

Comment: build new array <?php
  
  $NEW_ARRAY =array();
  foreach($array as $row)
  {
   
    
   $NEW_ARRAY[$row['vendor']][]= $row;

  }
  ?>

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the data is being stored/retrieved but here is how I might do such sorting - assuming the variable `$rows` is set contains an associative array of all rows (similar to the results of a basic database query) and assuming "vendor" is the column name for the vendors (TSZ, TSR, etc), "sku" is the name of the SKU column, and "store_price" is the name of the store price column:

```php
<?php

$vendorData = [];

foreach( $rows as $row ) {
    if( !isset($vendorData[$row['vendor']]) ) {
        $vendorData[$row['vendor']] = '';
    }
    $vendorData[$row['vendor']] .= '<div class="sku">' .
        $row['sku'] . '</div>' .
        '<div class="price">' . $row['store_price'] . '</div>';
}

foreach( $vendorData as $vendorName => $vendorHTML ) {
    echo '<div id="' . $vendorName . '" class="vendor">' .
        '<h3 class="name">' . $vendorName . '</h3>' .
        '<div class="data">' . $vendorHTML . '</div></div>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Its not showing in Group . For example TSZ div should contain all the TSZ , TSR div contain all the TSR  with store price .

Comment: I'm confused about what you are asking. Please elaborate. If you mean a MySQL GROUP expression, do not use it. It will roll all the entries with TSZ, TSR, etc. into one entry per vendor and your PHP will not have access to all the table rows.

Comment: Show in separate divs 
------------------------------------------------
TSZ 
  
TSZ K377    2300
----------------------------------------------
 TSR

TSR319     2250
TSR554      2300
TSR106     3500
---------------------------------------------

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding what you are asking. Please add your code and I will see if I can figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please look at the pictures in the question . There should be different divs based on vendor name and  Sku will be group under vendor name

Answer (score 0):

Here is thing what you need:-

```
$newDataRow = []
foreach($dataRows as $dataItemRow):
  $newDataRow[$dataRows['vendor']][] = $dataItemRow;
endforeach;
$op = '';
foreach($newDataRow as $vandorName => $vandorItemData):
  $op .= '<div class="vendor_item_group">';
  $op .= '<div class="vendor_name">'.$vandorName.'</div>';
  $op .= '<div class="item_group">';
  foreach($vandorItemData as $record):
  $op .= '<span>'.$record['sku'].'</span>';
  $op .= '<span>'.$record['price'].'</span>';
  endforeach;
  $op .='</div>';

  $op .= '</div>';
endforeach;

echo $op;
```

Output Should be like this:-

```
TSZ       TSR
TSZ K377  TSR319
2300      2250
          TSR319
           2300
```